# Unable to destroy session/logout in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I am trying to learn Rails API with React front end and have created a login, signup and logout feature. Currently, I am using `localstorage` to check if a user is signed in or registered. If the value is true, the logout button appears, and clicking logout empties the localstorage and sets the value to false. But I think this isn't the correct way of doing it since rails devise has its own session and logout endpoint. I tried writing some code for the destroy session and when testing it using the endpoint in POSTMAN it doesn't seem to work the way I want.

Here's the code:

```
class API::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(user_params[:email])
    if @user && @user.valid_password?(user_params[:password])
      session[:user_id]=@user.id
      sign_in :user, @user
      render json: @user
    elsif @user && not(@user.valid_password?(user_params[:password]))
      invalid_attempt
    else
      no_user
    end
  end



   def destroy
    puts "logout clicked"
    @user = User.find_by_email(user_params[:email])
    if @user.valid_password(user_params[:password]) && @user.destroy
      render :json => { success: "user was successfully deleted" }, :status => 201
    else
      render :json => { error: "user could not be deleted" }, :status => 422
    end
  end

  private

  def no_user
    render json: {error: "An account with this email doesn't exist. Please create a new one"}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

  def invalid_attempt
    render json: { error: "Your password isn't correct" }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
  end
  end
```

`http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out`

```
{
    "user":{
        "email":"test1@test.com",
        "password":"test1@test.com"
    }
}
```

Please note that this user does exist. Sending a delete request to `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out` isn't even logging the "logout clicked" and the status gives 204.

Comment: You're missing an `end` after `render json: {status: :failure, error: "Could not find user to sign out"}`. Also by telling the user that the email exists but the password is invalid you're making it much easier for an attacker to perform brute force password attacks. You should just give a 404 response code no matter if the email or password is invalid.

Comment: I also don't get how you think localstorage is involved. `session[:user_id] = @user.id` stores the value in the session and the default session backend is `ActionDistpatch::CookieStore`. Localstorage cannot be used as a session store as its not available to the server. https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/

Comment: @max Thanks there was a syntax error for the `end` statement. However, in local storage it just checks for user object which gets generated when logged in and registered. I haven't used `@user = User.find_by(session[:user_id])` at all in the front-end/local storage. I just want to know why logout isn't throwing any response when I hit the endpoint with the body.

Comment: Well it's probably a good thing. The logout action is supposed to sign the user out by calling `reset_session` which invalidates the session storage or by removing the user id key. Not remove the user! However none of this should really be done in this way. In Devise you use Warden to sign the user in and out and almost none of this code is needed to customize the responses which you can do without fudging up the logic of the controller.

Comment: @max So I'm using Rails as an API. Would I need to send something other than `{
    "user":{"email":"test1@test.com",  "password":"test1@test.com"}}` at `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out` to logout?

Comment: The user should only pass their email/password when logging in. You log out by just sending a delete request with no parameters.

Comment: I think you might want to just step away from what you have built and just do some research on how to authenticate APIs. You can use the session based approach if your just building it for your own consumption but the other approach is token based. In neither case do you need to reinvent the wheel like this.